# How to check what character a variable contains and compare it with a number?

Tags: shell-script, string

I have an hour record in which subsequent hours are written from 1 to 9 as numbers and then as subsequent alphabetic characters. I would like to save the time in a normal format, so I need to convert the letters of the alphabet into subsequent numbers.

I cut out the hour, minutes and seconds from the file name.

```
 endOfFile=${files: -9}
 currentTime=${endOfFile%.*}
 firstLetter=$(printf %.1s "$currentTime")
 echo "$firstLetter"
```

output:

```
 1

3

5

7

9

B

D

F

H

J
```

How can I check whether my variable contains a number or a letter, and if it is a letter, replace it with the appropriate number?

Comment: This question would be improved if sample input and sample output was provided. It is hard to tell how exactly you need to transform the letters to digits.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first question here and I didn't really know which parts would be appropriate

Comment: Tip : ASCII code for uppercase letters starts from $41 then increase following the alphabetical order. Can you capitalize from this and find your way ? Please do upgrade your question in case you face some blocker.

Comment: You mean you have an hour field expressed in hexadecimal and you want to convert that to decimal? Something `decimal=$(( 0x$hex ))` would do.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Hmmm… I don't think so since H and J appear in the output…

Comment: @MC68020, Ah yes of course, and hours go from 0 to 23. So maybe `decimal=$(( 24#$base24 ))`

Comment: What shell are you using? (try `echo $SHELL`). This is easier to achieve with bash extensions than if you have to remain POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 0):

From what I had suggested in comments : **from the ascii code :**

- get the ascii code for the first letter : `ord_fl=$(printf %d "'$firstletter")`
  (BTW the leading single quote is intended)
- Substract 55 : `hour=$(($ord_fl-55))`
  Since ascii codes for capitalized letters increment following the alphabetical order, starting from 65 (dec) and desired output for A should be 10.

---

Other and possibly much better idea suggested by Stéphane in comments : **base conversion from base 24 to decimal :**

```
hour=$(( 24#$firstletter ))
```

Caution : The exact syntax might depend on your shell.
In case your shell does not implement that sort of extension, you can always resort to `bc` and grab the output of :

```
echo "ibase=24; $firstletter" | bc
```

Comment: Note that that bc approach is not POSIX where ibase must be in the 2 .. 16 range.